# How Can I Add a Custom Password Validation in Laravels default Forgot Password System?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I want to change the validation for passwords when using Laravels default Forgot Password System. I need to do this so I can replace the password validation rule with this validation rule:

```
'password' => 'required|min:6|max:15|confirmed',
```

Specifically, I need to add the min/max changes.

However, I don't see anywhere in the ForgotPasswordController or ResetPasswordController where I can do this....

I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your `ResetPasswordController` just override the rules method.

```
  protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Rick I am glad it helped you.

Comment: @Amarnasan click on the tick it will turn green. :p

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I'm not the OP

Comment: @Amarnasan ohh okay.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with password data. You don't consider length of the password but also a valid format like password must not have any strange special characters or even space/blank character.

I want to share with you our basic solution yet effective that we have and been using it for many projects we built.

Create a custom Validator and register it by doing stated below.

1. Create a **custom validator for password format**, created a customClass for our customvalidator named "`CustomValidator`" extends the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` class to your customize class.

   public function validatePasswordFormat($attribute,$value,$parameters){
                return preg_match(("/^(?=.*)[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{2,25}$/"),$value);}

   alphanumeric with special characters !@#$%^&*()_+ 
   2-25 range of characters only. you can change this anytime.
2. Boot your Custom Validator to the app service Providers.

   ```
   public function boot(){
      Validator::resolver(function($translator,$data,$rules,$messages){
      return new CustomValidator($translator,$data,$rules,$messages);
   ```

   });
       }
3. Use is easily by doing in your request like this.

   **'password' => "required|password_format"**

   and then in your message response for error.

   **'password_format' => "Invalid password format. blah blah blah"**

I hope this will help you.